# How to attach a custom attached property to a property of my control?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got an attached property that I can attach like so

```
<SomeControl x:FocusExtension:IsFocused="{Binding ..whatever}" />
```

I've got a control that's wrapping a TextBox.  So what I want to do is..

```
<TextBoxWrapper TextBox.x:FocusExtension:IsFocused="{Binding ..whatever}" />
```

Is there any way for me to accomplish this from this without modifying the wrapper?

I want to attach the attached property to a property in my TextBoxWrapper.

Comment: Can you explain more about the intended result? What is TextBox.x:FocusExtension:IsFocused="{Binding ..whatever}"  doing

Comment: Not clearly understand what you want... What is "TextBox.x..." and why it's looks like that

Comment: @SethKitchen Sorry, I've updated with the question.  I know that way is wrong, but I thought it would imply what I was intending.